# A single action in Autoscale configuration

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Whenever I edit a scale group configuration in softlayer, it returns the following message. "A single action is required for a policy"
What is a single action for a policy ? 
There is no way to edit a cpu rate in policy since the error message.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug already submitted on that matter.
Nevertheless you can work around this by checking that only a single action is contained by policy (re create the action if it has more than a single one). Furthermore, you can find these restrictions in the API documentation:

> actions: The actions to perform upon any trigger hit. Currently this
>   must be a single value.
>
> scaleActions: The scale actions to perform upon any trigger hit.
>   Currently this must be a single value.

I hope it helps.

Comment: One scale action can be set per policy. right? Even if there is a single action, it returns same error. I've also implemented it using java API and add one action for policy, but it still returns the same error.

Comment: I've tested this scenario and wasn't able to reproduce your issue. I would suggest to submit a ticket with the necessary steps to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are trying to edit a **Scale Group** which has **two scaleActions** (Unfotunately, it's possible to add more than one **scaleActions through API - known issue**) and you are trying to **clean the scaleActions and set this to on**e, this is an issue from SoftLayer's side, currently there is an issue about it that Developers are working to fix it.

You can submit a ticket to track this and SoftLayer would delete the scaleActions for you, anyway I will let you know any news.

Meanwhile, as workaround you can delete the Scale Group and create new one.

---

> **Updated**

**The extra scaleActions were deleted**, **please be careful to avoid create/edit Policy with 2 or 0 scaleActions** (I recommend this because we have a known issue about this). A Policy just should be created/edited with 1 scaleActions. Please try again.